# Main Logo REFUSES to center

Tags: css, centering

I've tried every trick I can think of, but the main logo on my home page absolutely REFUSES to center itself horizontally:

http://aksarbenribfest.bugs3.com/public_html/#!/page_home

It's off slightly to the right, which is especially noticable because it's right below a centered header element.

I appreciate all the help!

THANKS!

Robert
Omaha, Nebraska

Comment: If you could include some code that would be nice, though using margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; usually does the trick.

Comment: @Robert Conner Nice page!  Where did you come up with that menu?

Comment: I bought the template I'm using from a designer named Cowboy.  Here's what it looks like in it's stock/original format: http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/39062.html

Answer (score 2):

This is because the container section#content is smaller than the logo itself

```
section #content {
  width: 940px;
}

.logo {
  width: 976px;
}
```

The logo is overflowing the container to the right and since the container is centered the logo appears offcenter. You can fix the problem by either making the logo smaller or the container larger

Comment: Works like a charm!  I spent 45 minutes looking at every parameter I could think of...but THAT one never occurred to me!  I appreciate the help!